# Can I form a measure given the density of a set of natural numbers?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A\subset \mathbb N$. Define $\bar{d}(A)=\limsup_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{|A\cap[1,k]|}{k}$.

My question is, can I consider $\bar{d}(A)$ to be a finitely additive measure of $A$? I think no because for disjoint $A,B$, I can only say $\bar{d}(A\cup B)\leq \bar{d}(A)+\bar{d}(B)$.

But can we somehow get a measure from $\bar{d}$? Like, say, if the limit exists? (If the limit exists, then $\bar{d}$ is a finitely additive measure. But the limit may not exist always!).

Comment: A measure is not required to be defined on every set. So there's no reason you couldn't regard the density as a finitely additive measure, _on_ the class of sets for which it exists. Not that that does anything much for you as far as I can see; finitely additive measures are really nothing like measures.

Comment: See [*Finitely additive measures on* $\mathbb N$](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419290032U) by Eric K. van Douwen (1992), and google "finitely additive measures" along with "van Douwen" for related work.